# Photo and post privacy on Facebook

Tags: facebook, privacy

I want to make sure the photos I put on Facebook are only shared with family and close friends.

How can I stop a friend letting his friends see and share my photos? I want to keep them my private property far way from the eyes of paedophiles and marketing companies.

Answer (score 4):

The only real answer is:  Don't post your photos.

No matter what settings you choose, if someone you have shared them with is determined enough they can simply take a screenshot, make an image file with that, and share it.

Comment: Or they can simply save the image from their browser (right click, Save Image As...) and post it.